# Seeing the syntax error while updating the table with column value

Tags: mysql

I have the below query that I'm using to update the master table from the src table for NPI column. However, I'm seeing the following syntax error.
Database: MySql on AWS
Version: 5.7.12

```
UPDATE master hcp_mt
INNER JOIN 
select x.NPI from (select 
CASE 
WHEN period_end IS NULL THEN 5 
WHEN period_end IS NOT NULL THEN -30
ELSE NULL 
END  as 'NPI'
from src ) x
ON hcp_mt.r_id = x.r_id
and hcp_mt.l_id = x.l_id
and hcp_mt.p_num  =  x.p_num
SET hcp_mt.NPI = x.NPI
```

**Error:**

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select x.NPI from (select 
CASE 
WHEN period_end IS NULL THEN 5 
W' at line 3
```

Could someone please help me with this? What could be the possible reason?

Comment: You have to put `()` around the subquery when you join with it.

Comment: @Barmar You mean like this?

UPDATE master hcp_mt
INNER JOIN 
(select x.NPI from (select 
CASE 
WHEN period_end IS NULL THEN 5 
WHEN period_end IS NOT NULL THEN -30
ELSE NULL 
END  as 'NPI'
from src ) x
ON hcp_mt.r_id = x.r_id
and hcp_mt.l_id = x.l_id
and hcp_mt.p_num  =  x.p_num)
SET hcp_mt.NPI = x.NPI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `SELECT` that's not needed, just join with the subquery.

```
UPDATE master hcp_mt
INNER JOIN (
    select 
        r_id, l_id, p_num,
        CASE 
            WHEN period_end IS NULL THEN 5 
            ELSE -30
        END  as 'NPI'
    from src ) x 
ON hcp_mt.r_id = x.r_id
    and hcp_mt.l_id = x.l_id
    and hcp_mt.p_num  =  x.p_num
SET hcp_mt.NPI = x.NPI
```

You also left out the other columns that you're joining with in the subquery.

There's no need for 3 cases in the `CASE` expression. Either a column is null or not, there's no third possibility.

There's also not really a need for a subquery at all. Just join with the table and put the `CASE` in the `SET` clause.

```
UPDATE master AS hcp_mt
JOIN src AS x
ON hcp_mt.r_id = x.r_id
    and hcp_mt.l_id = x.l_id
    and hcp_mt.p_num  =  x.p_num
SET hcp_mt.NPI = CASE 
        WHEN period_end IS NULL THEN 5
        ELSE -30
    END
```

This is likely to perform much better if the column you're joining on are indexed.